# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ticketCost' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

So I want a error message to appear saying 'Sorry, invalid input' when I input anything other than child,adult and senior or 3D and 2D. And then I want it to ask the user again to input the ticketType and movieType but it comes up with

```
"File "python", line 33, in <module>
  File "python", line 27, in buyOneTicket
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ticketCost' referenced before assignment"
```

.

```
print ('Welcome to RareCinema Ticketing System')
num = int(input('How many tickets would you like to buy?'))


def buyOneTicket() :
        ticketType = input('Enter the type of ticket (Child/Adult/Senior)?')
        movieType = input('Enter the movie type (2D/3D)?')

        if ticketType == ("child"):
            if movieType == ("2D"):
                ticketCost = 16
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 19

        elif ticketType == ('adult'):
            if movieType == ('2D'):
                ticketCost = 22
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 27

        elif ticketType == ('senior'):
            if movieType == ('2D'):
                ticketCost = 14
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 18

        return ticketCost
ticketCost=0


count = 1
while (count <= num):
     ticketCost = ticketCost  + buyOneTicket() 
     count = count + 1

if ticket_type != ('child') and ('adult') and ('senior'):
  if movie_type != ('2D') and ('3D'):
    print ('Sorry, you have entered an invalid input')
    ticketType = input('Enter the type of ticket (Child/Adult/Senior)?')
    movieType = input('Enter the movie type (2D/3D)?')

else:
print('Your total cost for ' +str(num)+ ' is ', ticketCost )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def buyOneTicket() :
        ticketType = input('Enter the type of ticket (Child/Adult/Senior)?')
        movieType = input('Enter the movie type (2D/3D)?')

        if ticketType == ("child"):
            if movieType == ("2D"):
                ticketCost = 16
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 19

        elif ticketType == ('adult'):
            if movieType == ('2D'):
                ticketCost = 22
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 27

        elif ticketType == ('senior'):
            if movieType == ('2D'):
                ticketCost = 14
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 18

        return ticketCost
```

So the last line of your `buyOneTicket` method is where this is happening, and the reason is that `ticketCost` is only ever created if your `ticketType` matches one of your listed categories. You can consider creating an `else` condition at the end which will ask the user again:

```
def buyOneTicket() :
        ticketType = input('Enter the type of ticket (Child/Adult/Senior)?')
        movieType = input('Enter the movie type (2D/3D)?')

        if ticketType == ("child"):
            if movieType == ("2D"):
                ticketCost = 16
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 19

        elif ticketType == ('adult'):
            if movieType == ('2D'):
                ticketCost = 22
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 27

        elif ticketType == ('senior'):
            if movieType == ('2D'):
                ticketCost = 14
            elif movieType == ('3D'):
                ticketCost = 18

        else:
            print('You did not pick a valid ticket type. Try again.')
            return buyOneTicket()

    return ticketCost
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked, I guess I was just put the error message in the wrong place :)